# nginx ssl_preload ssh,http,https setup

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-config

I saw examples of combining HTTPS/SSH
Selecting an upstream based on SSL protocol version:

```
map $ssl_preread_protocol $upstream {
    default   ssh.example.com:22;
    "TLSv1.2" new.example.com:443;
}

# ssh and https on the same port
server {
    listen      192.168.0.1:443;
    proxy_pass  $upstream;
    ssl_preread on;
}
```

But i don't know how to combine SSH, HTTPS(TLS) and HTTP on same port? Is this even possible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fast answer

you should change type of mapping and set upstream blocks.

```
#set block with web upstream
#set block with ssh upstream

map $ssl_preread_protocol $upstream {
    ""   ssh.example.com:22;       #change to ssh upstream
    "TLSv1.2" new.example.com:443; #change to web upstream
    default new.example.com:443;   #change to web upstream
}
```

#### Normal answer

But Fast answer is wrong too. In second place of `"TLSv1.2" new.example.com:443;` should stay name of streaming like `web` or `ssh` or `my_home_server`.

e.g `"TLSv1.2" new.example.com:443;` -> `"TLSv1.2" web`.

And you should set upstream blocks.

```
   upstream web {
       server new.example.com:443;
   }
   upstream ssh {
       server ssh.example.com:22;
   }
```

#### Just answer

I see that you try to use the subdomain for ssh.  It is not necessary.
You can choose not to use subdomain in upstream map with `$ssl_preread_protocol` and change SSL server listen port fro 443 to 4433(or any else). e.g. ssh and https in same port by nginx.

After combining information from top we can set that

```
 stream {
       upstream ssh {
           server localhost:22;   # ssh port in our server
       }

       upstream web {
           server localhost:4433; # SSL web page port in our server
       }

       map $ssl_preread_protocol $upstream {
           "" ssh;    #if $ssl_preread_protocol is EMPTY try to use ssh upstream
           "TLSv1.2" web;  #if $ssl_preread_protocol is TLSv1.2(may be add more TLSv1.3) try to use web upstream    
           default web;
       }

       server {
         listen 443;    
         proxy_pass $upstream;  #send connetion to specific upstream that correspondintly map block
         ssl_preread on;  #allow to read $ssl_preread_protocol variable
       }
```

and in  block with ssl cert has only one changes port from 443 to 4433.

```
##block server 80 port
. . .
server {


    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name www.example.com example.com; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
#changed from 443 to 4433
    listen [::]:4433 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
#changed from 443 to 4433
    listen 4433 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
. . .
##block redirect from http to https
```

I hope this can help someone because I have been looking for this solution for a long time.